# What is the best usage of tsdb?

Tags: opentsdb

I found opentsdb as a powerful monitoring system. it has a structure like proc.loadavg.1min 1234567890 1.35 host=A.

But my questions are:

1- is it good for logging in php?

2- can I store every log data in it?

3- and please let me know if there is a good library for php for working with opnetsdb for e.g ( send data to opentsdb by php )

it not yet clear to me.
I would be tankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion openTSDB is not a monitoring system but a way to store time series.

If you want to build a monitoring tool you'll need a bigger set of tools, including a way to feed your monitored metrics to the database and a way to display them.

For example you can use Logstash and statsd to collect, aggregate and send your metrics. For the display you can use a tool called Grafana.

openTSDB is just an options for storing it, but you can also Graphite or InfluxDB.